# Django password reset not sending mail

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views, django-4.0

when i am resetting my password in django everything goes well but  i am not getting any mail .

```
urls.py path('password_reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('blogapp:password_reset_done')),name='password_reset'),
    path('reset_password_sent/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='blogapp/password_reset_confirm.html',success_url=reverse_lazy('blogapp:password_reset_complete')),name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),name='password_reset_complete'),

]
```

Comment: Does the email address exist and is the User.is_active flag True and does the user have a usable password? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView

Comment: @IainShelvington When I see the django admin email exist there and there is active flag which ticked and I used the UserCreationForm for password.